# pypsark convert for loop to map

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataset that has null values

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   0|null|
|   1|null|   0|
|null|   1|   0|
|   1|   0|   0|
|   1|   0|   0|
|null|   0|   1|
|   1|   1|   0|
|   1|   1|null|
|null|   1|   0|
+----+----+----+
```

I wrote a function to count the percentage of null values of each column in the dataset and removing those columns from the dataset. Below is the function

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
def calc_null_percent(df, strength=None):
    if strength is None:
        strength = 80
    total_count = df.count()
    null_cols = []
    df2 = df.select([F.count(F.when(F.col(c).contains('None') | \
                            F.col(c).contains('NULL') | \
                            (F.col(c) == '' ) | \
                            F.col(c).isNull() | \
                            F.isnan(c), c 
                           )).alias(c)
                    for c in df.columns])
    for i in df2.columns:
        get_null_val = df2.first()[i]
        if (get_null_val/total_count)*100 > strength:
            null_cols.append(i)
            
    df = df.drop(*null_cols)
    return df
```

I am using a for loop to get the columns based on the condition. Can we use map or Is there any other way to optimise the for loop in pyspark?

Comment: one optimization would be to lose the `df2.first()` within the loop. that can be a static outside the loop as it need not be collected multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it with list comprehension.

```
data_ls = [
    (1, 0, 'blah'),
    (0, None, 'None'),
    (None, 1, 'NULL'),
    (1, None, None)
]

data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['id1', 'id2', 'id3'])

# +----+----+----+
# | id1| id2| id3|
# +----+----+----+
# |   1|   0|blah|
# |   0|null|None|
# |null|   1|NULL|
# |   1|null|null|
# +----+----+----+
```

Now, calculate the percentage of nulls in a dataframe and `collect()` it for further use.

```
# total row count
tot_count = data_sdf.count()

# percentage of null records per column
data_null_perc_sdf = data_sdf. \
select(*[(func.sum((func.col(k).isNull() | (func.upper(k).isin(['NONE', 'NULL']))).cast('int')) / tot_count).alias(k+'_nulls_perc') for k in data_sdf.columns])

# +--------------+--------------+--------------+
# |id1_nulls_perc|id2_nulls_perc|id3_nulls_perc|
# +--------------+--------------+--------------+
# |          0.25|           0.5|          0.75|
# +--------------+--------------+--------------+

# collection of the dataframe for list comprehension
data_null_perc = data_null_perc_sdf.collect()
# [Row(id1_nulls_perc=0.25, id2_nulls_perc=0.5, id3_nulls_perc=0.75)]

threshold = 0.5

# retain columns of `data_sdf` that have more null records than aforementioned threshold
cols2drop = [k for k in data_sdf.columns if data_null_perc[0][k+'_nulls_perc'] >= threshold]
# ['id2', 'id3']
```

Use `cols2drop` variable to drop the columns from `data_sdf` in the next step

```
new_data_sdf = data_sdf.drop(*cols2drop)

# +----+
# | id1|
# +----+
# |   1|
# |   0|
# |null|
# |   1|
# +----+
```

Comment: collect brings the entire code to the driver. Can you please give another way without using collect?

Comment: so does `.first()`. also, in this case, the collection is very small as it is 1 row only

Comment: Yeah but when I am using data with millions of rows both first and collect will have a problem. Is there any other solution?

Comment: i don't think it'll be a problem as you'll only collect (bring in) 1 row. i'll post another answer if i come up with any other ideas.

Comment: @samkart is right here I think. It should already be processed, and just bring in one row.